# How to run LibreOffice in a WebBrowser?

Tags: libreoffice

When `libreoffice5.2 --help` is issued the help does not indicate how to run libreoffice in a webbrowser.

**Expected**

The aim is to run libreoffice in a webbrowser so that it could be accessed by navigating to http://localhost:8080 for example.

**Discussion**

[This Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/632044/215599) was found, but this seems not to be applicable anymore for later versions.

Comment: Did you check https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/LibreOffice_Online and the build instructions in the developement's section there?

Comment: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Using_LibreOffice_in_a_Web_Browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That's not a feature which LibreOffice supports.

Software which can run either as a desktop application or in a browser is rare -- in most cases, applications will only support one of the two environments. If you want a word processor which can run in a browser, your best bet will be to look for one that specifically supports that.

(There are some complicated ways you could *access* an instance of LibreOffice in a browser -- for instance, running it in a VNC session and using a browser-based VNC client to view that -- but they are probably more trouble than they're worth.)

Answer (score 4):

I would refer you to [this link](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/tag/libreoffice-online-en/) which says LibreOffice Online source code has been released and pre-built Docker images are available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/libreoffice/online/).

However, actually using it is not staightforward, and you might be better off using Collabora either on its own or (even easier) within OwnCloud or NextCloud; look on the respective websites for a how-to or see [here](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/) and [here](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/).

Sorry for posting a link-only answer but the LibreOffice Online setup is complex and you might want to document yourself before going that route. On the other hand, Collabora already has some good tutorials available and I wouldn't be adding much.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Docker image is supposed to help here -- Docker images do not run in a browser.

Comment: Well, needless to say, the Docker image is to be deployed on the server where you install the web server, LibreOffice and possibly OwnCloud/NextCloud.